# Error when trying to detect if bash is installed

Tags: shell, package

I am writing a script to output if bash is installed. I know there is `dpkg -s` for it , but I want keep it simple.

When I enter this in (putty) telnet:

```
    echo $(opkg list_installed bash* | grep "bash*")
```

If it's installed I get this echo

```
    bash - 4.3.30-r0.1
```

If it's not installed I get an empty line.

My script:

```
if opkg list_installed bash* | grep "bash*" &>/dev/null;
then
    echo "[DEBUG]: Found: " $(opkg list_installed bash* | grep "bash*")
else
    echo "[DEBUG]: Bash is not installed" 
fi
```

When I run this script: if it's installed this is the output:

```
    root@zero:~# ./test.sh
    [DEBUG]: bash - 4.3.30-r0.1
    root@zero:~#
```

If bash isn't installed I get an error instead the echo that it isn't installed:

```
    root@zero:~# ./test.sh
    -sh: ./test.sh: not found
    root@zero:~#
```

Comment: What is your default shell _when bash is not installed_ ?? what header you are using in your script?

Comment: you solved my problem #!/bin/bash    changed it to /sh and is working now

Answer (score 0):

Print `bash` version, or if it's not installed print "*no bash*":

```
bash --version || echo no bash
```